# Looking for a customer support oriented ticketing system

Tags: web-apps, email, saas, help-desk, support-tracker

We are looking for a ticketing system where customers can write to us via a particular email address (support@product.com) and have their messages turned into tickets that multiple people can work on internally. We need the following features:

- Cloud based / SaaS
- Seamless email support (as noted above, end consumers should be able to write emails and get emails back with responses)
- Support for internal notes in tickets that are not shown to the end customer
- Support for multiple "agents" (people) with internal aliases that are not shown to the end customer
- Support for configurable separate "queues" or "views" for different products, languages, topics, etc.
- No more expensive that $20 per agent per month, preferently less

We are currently using [Zendesk Support](https://www.zendesk.com/support/), however two of the features we need (internal aliases and separate views) are features exclusive to their "Professional" plan which at the time of this writing is $50 per agent per month, prohibitively expensive for a small start up (it'd add up to a 4 figure bill per year if we went that route). So we are looking for better priced alternatives to switch.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but check out spiceworks help desk. Can't beat their pricing.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider our app - [Jitbit Helpdesk](https://www.jitbit.com/hosted-helpdesk/)? Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers so I'm not posting any reviews/pros/cons since I'm obviously biased.

We have both SaaS and self-hosted versions and the SaaS is **$69 for 4 agents** ($17 per agent). All the features you mentioned are there.